# Make divs on same row the same height - Dynamic Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on an application that generates dynamic content and displays them on floating divs.  Each div takes 49% width of the page.  The problem I'm running into is that the height of the divs vary depending on the content.

What I'm looking to do is make the divs on the same row the same height.  Any suggestions?

```css
.item {
    background: #c4c4c4;
    width: 49%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">
        Test
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Hello.
        Sample <br>
        Content <br>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Test<br>
        Sample Content
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Test
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [**`CSS3 flexbox`**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to make the `#container` adapt flexible box layout.

Default value of flex-wrap is `nowrap` so it aligns in a single row. Use `flex-wrap: wrap` to create multiple rows based on item's width.

Current browser support for Flexbox is pretty good: [**Can I use Flexbox?**](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* Wrap after the items fill the row */
  
  /* Safari specific rules */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item {
  background: #c4c4c4;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 49%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Hello. Sample
    <br>Content
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Test
    <br>Sample Content
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is flexbox compatible with all browsers?

Comment: It is compatible with all major browsers now including IE10 with  `-ms-` prefix

Comment: Works perfect.  Thank you

Comment: Please use Edge. IE9 is so outdated and will not be used by anyone soon.

Answer (score 1):

Use display: table on the containing div, and display: block on your "table cell" divs.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer involves using the display: table property in CSS. It is similar to table scaffolding, but allows much more flexibility with CSS and has more browser support than flexbox.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="item">
        Test
        </div>
        <div class="item">
        Hello.
        Sample <br>
        Content <br>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="item">
        Test<br>
        Sample Content
    </div>
        <div class="item">
            Test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}

.item {
    background: #c4c4c4;
    width: 49%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/q5jyfuy6/

Comment: Thank you.  But I can't add another div with class row to my html.  The content is being generated dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You can add like **height:40px;** in your .item class to make height of the divs independent of the content.

```
.item {
    background: #c4c4c4;
    width: 49%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    height:40px;
}
```