# How Can I manage Box Overlay Height same for more than one box

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I do manage overlay box height same if text line is not same, below is my dummy code, If You can manage it with jQuery or JS, please give me a solution to resolve it, Thanks Your valuable time to try to give solution.

```css
.box {
display:table;
width:100%;

}
.box-col {
display:table-cell;
margin:0 2px;
height:300px;
border:1px solid gray;
position:relative;
width:33%;
}
.box-overlay {
position:absolute;
text-align:center;
padding:5px;
left:0;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
.box-overlay h2,.box-overlay p {
color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
 <div class="box-col">
<img src="">
 <div class="box-overlay">
 <h2>Title</h2>
 <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of s</p>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="box-col">
<img src="">
 <div class="box-overlay">
 <h2>Title</h2>
 <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
 </div>
 </div>
 
  <div class="box-col">
<img src="">
 <div class="box-overlay">
 <h2>Title</h2>
 <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</p>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could solution in following link [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747709/make-divs-on-same-row-the-same-height-dynamic-content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the overlays, find the tallest one, then apply that height to all of the overlays. Here's a solution using jQuery.

```js
var tallest = 0,
    $overlays = $('.box-overlay');
$('.box-overlay').each(function() {
  var thisHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
  if (thisHeight > tallest) {
    tallest = thisHeight;
  }
});
$overlays.height(tallest);
```

```css
.box {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.box-col {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 0 2px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  position: relative;
  width: 33%;
}

.box-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.box-overlay h2,
.box-overlay p {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-col">
    <img src="">
    <div class="box-overlay">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of s</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box-col">
    <img src="">
    <div class="box-overlay">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box-col">
    <img src="">
    <div class="box-overlay">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a same height on all the overlays and height will not change irrespective of the text line then you can include max-height:100px; in the .box-overlay class.

```
.box-overlay {
 position:absolute;
 text-align:center;
 padding:5px;
 left:0;
 bottom:0;
 width:100%;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 max-height:100px;
}
```